# In Svelte, is #key the proper way to make a block reactive if it makes no local reference to variables?

Tags: svelte

In the code below, I am calling a function (`getFormattedValue`) to obtain the value to display. That is a wrapper around another function (`node.getFormattedAttrValue`) that supplies a common parameter, `data` so I don't have to keep repeating the data parameter for each attribute I'm displaying... the only thing each must provide is its name. But after doing this, the component body stopped reacting (e.g. on change to data). Apparently not having `data` in the `{ }` tags made them non-reactive. But I don't want to keep repeating that same parameter. So what to do?

```
<script>
  export let data, node
  const getFormattedValue = (synonym) => node.getFormattedAttrValue(data,synonym)

</script>

<Card>
  <span slot="Body">
    <li>{getFormattedValue("CURRENT_VALUE")}</li>
    <li>{getFormattedValue("MIN_VALUE")}</li>
    <li>{getFormattedValue("MAX_VALUE")}</li>
    <li>{getFormattedValue("PCT_CONSUMED")}%</li>
  </span>
</Card>
```

The only way I could get it to react again without putting `data` back into the parameter list is to add a **key** block on it:

```
  {#key data}
    <li>{getFormattedValue("CURRENT_VALUE")}</li>
    <li>{getFormattedValue("MIN_VALUE")}</li>
    <li>{getFormattedValue("MAX_VALUE")}</li>
    <li>{getFormattedValue("PCT_CONSUMED")}%</li>
   {/key}
```

But I read that `key` completely destroys everything and rebuilds it, so it sounds rather heavy-handed. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could put the names in an array and build the list elements via an `#each` block. This would also eliminate the repetition of the function call..

Comment: This is a simplified example of the real code. My real code has numerous complex display patterns for the various values, so it doesn't lend itself to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define functions reactively as well:

```js
$: getFormattedValue = (synonym) => node.getFormattedAttrValue(data,synonym)
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/ce0950b79d9f496ab38223aa61c0a91e?version=3.55.1)